Why image retrieval from SQLite database is failing
I am saving an image in the SQLite database with the  code below:
import sqlite3
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import messagebox
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import io

# Connect to SQLite database (or create it if it doesn't exist)
conn = sqlite3.connect('employee_vehicle.db')
c = conn.cursor()

# Create table
c.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS employee_vehicle
             (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
              registration_no TEXT,
              chassis_no TEXT,
              name TEXT,
              designation TEXT,
              photo BLOB,
              mobile_no TEXT,
              address TEXT,
              gender TEXT)''')
conn.commit()

# Function to insert data into the database
def insert_data(reg_no, ch_no, name, desig, photo, mob_no, addr, gender):
    with conn:
        c.execute("INSERT INTO employee_vehicle (registration_no, chassis_no, name, designation, photo, mobile_no, address, gender) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", 
                  (reg_no, ch_no, name, desig, photo, mob_no, addr, gender))
        conn.commit()

# Function to load photo
def load_photo():
    file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=[("Image files", "*.jpg;*.png")])
    if file_path:
        img = Image.open(file_path)
        img.thumbnail((100, 100))
        img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
        photo_label.config(image=img)
        photo_label.image = img
        with open(file_path, 'rb') as file:
            photo_data.set(file.read())

# Function to submit form
def submit_form():
    reg_no = reg_no_entry.get()
    ch_no = ch_no_entry.get()
    name = name_entry.get()
    desig = desig_entry.get()
    photo = photo_data.get()
    mob_no = mob_no_entry.get()
    addr = addr_entry.get()
    gender = gender_var.get()

    if all([reg_no, ch_no, name, desig, photo, mob_no, addr, gender]):
        insert_data(reg_no, ch_no, name, desig, photo, mob_no, addr, gender)
        messagebox.showinfo("Success", "Data inserted successfully!")
    else:
        messagebox.showerror("Error", "Please fill all fields!")

# GUI setup
root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Employee Vehicle Registration Form")

tk.Label(root, text="Registration No:").grid(row=0, column=0)
reg_no_entry = tk.Entry(root)
reg_no_entry.grid(row=0, column=1)

tk.Label(root, text="Chassis No:").grid(row=1, column=0)
ch_no_entry = tk.Entry(root)
ch_no_entry.grid(row=1, column=1)

tk.Label(root, text="Name:").grid(row=2, column=0)
name_entry = tk.Entry(root)
name_entry.grid(row=2, column=1)

tk.Label(root, text="Designation:").grid(row=3, column=0)
desig_entry = tk.Entry(root)
desig_entry.grid(row=3, column=1)

tk.Label(root, text="Photo:").grid(row=4, column=0)
photo_label = tk.Label(root)
photo_label.grid(row=4, column=1)
photo_data = tk.StringVar()
tk.Button(root, text="Load Photo", command=load_photo).grid(row=4, column=2)

tk.Label(root, text="Mobile No:").grid(row=5, column=0)
mob_no_entry = tk.Entry(root)
mob_no_entry.grid(row=5, column=1)

tk.Label(root, text="Address:").grid(row=6, column=0)
addr_entry = tk.Entry(root)
addr_entry.grid(row=6, column=1)

tk.Label(root, text="Gender:").grid(row=7, column=0)
gender_var = tk.StringVar()
tk.Radiobutton(root, text="Male", variable=gender_var, value="Male").grid(row=7, column=1)
tk.Radiobutton(root, text="Female", variable=gender_var, value="Female").grid(row=7, column=2)

tk.Button(root, text="Submit", command=submit_form).grid(row=8, columnspan=3)

root.mainloop()

# Close the database connection when done
conn.close()
    

I try to retrieve and save the photo in the file directory with the below code:
import sqlite3
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import serialization, hashes
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric import padding
from pyzbar.pyzbar import decode
from PIL import Image
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QFileDialog
import sys
import cv2
import numpy as np
import io
import tempfile
import os

def decrypt_data(private_key, encrypted_data):
    try:
        decrypted_data = private_key.decrypt(
            encrypted_data,
            padding.OAEP(
                mgf=padding.MGF1(algorithm=hashes.SHA256()),
                algorithm=hashes.SHA256(),
                label=None
            )
        )
        return decrypted_data.decode()
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Debug: Error in decrypt_data: {e}")
        raise

def process_qr_code(image_path):
    try:
        img = Image.open(image_path)
        qr_code_data = decode(img)
        
        if qr_code_data:
            qr_text = qr_code_data[0].data.decode()
            try:
                ch_no, encrypted_data_hex = qr_text.split(":")
                encrypted_data = bytes.fromhex(encrypted_data_hex)
            except ValueError:
                print("Invalid QR code data format.")
                print("Employee does not exist. Output: 0")
                return
            
            private_key_path = f"{ch_no}_private.pem"
            
            try:
                with open(private_key_path, "rb") as key_file:
                    private_key = serialization.load_pem_private_key(
                        key_file.read(),
                        password=None
                    )
                
                decrypted_data = decrypt_data(private_key, encrypted_data)
                
                try:
                    name = decrypted_data.split(",")[0].split(":")[1].strip()
                    mobile_no = decrypted_data.split(",")[1].split(":")[1].strip()
                    
                    print(f"Employee QR verified. Name: {name}")
                    
                    # Retrieve and save employee image
                    retrieve_and_save_image(name)
                    
                    # Capture and recognize face
                    capture_and_recognize_face(f"{name}_retrieve.jpg")
                
                except Exception as e:
                    print(f"Error parsing decrypted data: {e}")
                    print("Employee does not exist. Output: 0")
                    return

            except Exception as e:
                print(f"Error processing data: {e}")
                print("Employee does not exist. Output: 0")
        else:
            print("No QR code found in the image.")
            print("Employee does not exist. Output: 0")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error processing QR code: {e}")
        print("Employee does not exist. Output: 0")

def retrieve_and_save_image(name):
    try:
        conn = sqlite3.connect('employee_vehicle.db')
        c = conn.cursor()
        
        c.execute("SELECT photo FROM employee_vehicle WHERE name = ?", (name,))
        result = c.fetchone()
        
        if result and result[0]:
            photo_blob = result[0]
            
            # Ensure photo_blob is in bytes
            if isinstance(photo_blob, str):
                photo_blob = photo_blob.encode('latin1')  # Convert if needed
            
            # Create the directory if it doesn't exist
            current_dir = os.getcwd()
            image_dir = os.path.join(current_dir, 'retrieved_images')
            os.makedirs(image_dir, exist_ok=True)
            
            image_path = os.path.join(image_dir, f"{name}_retrieve.jpg")
            
            # Save the image using PIL
            image = Image.open(io.BytesIO(photo_blob))
            image.save(image_path)
            print(f"Image '{name}' retrieved and saved as '{image_path}'.")
            
            # Try opening the saved image
            try:
                saved_image = Image.open(image_path)
                saved_image.show()
                print("Saved image opened successfully.")
            except Exception as e:
                print(f"Error opening saved image: {e}")
        else:
            print(f"No image found for '{name}'.")
        
        conn.close()
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error accessing database: {e}")
       

def capture_and_recognize_face(image_path):
    face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(cv2.data.haarcascades + 'haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
    recognizer = cv2.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer_create()

    # Load the image from file using PIL
    stored_face_image = Image.open(image_path).convert('L')
    stored_face_image = np.array(stored_face_image)

    if stored_face_image is None:
        print(f"Error loading image from file: {image_path}")
        return

    face_image_resized = cv2.resize(stored_face_image, (200, 200))
    recognizer.train([face_image_resized], np.array([0]))

    video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    if not video_capture.isOpened():
        print("Unable to access webcam.")
        return
    
    ret, frame = video_capture.read()
    if ret:
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, scaleFactor=1.3, minNeighbors=5)
        
        if len(faces) > 0:
            (x, y, w, h) = faces[0]
            face_image = gray[y:y+h, x:x+w]
            face_image_resized = cv2.resize(face_image, (200, 200))

            label, confidence = recognizer.predict(face_image_resized)
            
            if label == 0 and confidence < 100:
                print("Facial recognition succeeded. Employee verified. Output: 1")
            else:
                print("Facial recognition failed. Output: 0")
        else:
            print("No face found in the captured image.")
            print("Employee does not exist. Output: 0")
    else:
        print("Unable to capture image from webcam.")
    
    video_capture.release()

def upload_image():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    options = QFileDialog.Options()
    file_path, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(
        None,
        "Select an Image File",
        "",
        "Image Files (*.jpg *.png *.jpeg);;All Files (*)",
        options=options
    )
    
    if file_path:
        print(f"Selected file: {file_path}")
        process_qr_code(file_path)
    else:
        print("No file selected or operation cancelled.")
        print("Employee does not exist. Output: 0")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    upload_image()

It is giving me this error:
Error accessing database: cannot identify image file <_io.BytesIO object at 0x000002E247154BD0>
Error parsing decrypted data: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Pawa_retrieve.jpg'

I don't think this is a database error. The error could be happening anywhere in the try block. Get rid of try/except so you get a full traceback, and post that.

Please read about [mcve] then click [edit] and ensure your post is complete and runnable. At the moment it has no import statements and is not complete or minimal. Thanks.

Thank you for the suggestions this is the complete and fully runnable code

You're doing photo_blob.encode('latin1').  Are you sure that's right?  How do you know?

the issue isn't the "complete" part, but the "minimal" part because that code isn't minimal.

Here's a minimal example of how to insert and extract images from an sqlite database. I use a bash script with the sqlite3 executable  to set up the database, and insert and extract an image that way. Then, I use Python to add or extract records from that database in the second part.

Here's the bash to set it up and insert/extract an image:
#!/bin/bash
DB_FILE="example.db"

# Discard any previous database file
rm "$DB_FILE" 2> /dev/null

# Create a table of people, with their names and images in the database
sqlite3 "$DB_FILE" <<EOF
CREATE TABLE People(
  id integer primary key autoincrement,
  image BLOB,
  name text
)
EOF

# See the tables present in the database
echo Following tables are present in database:
echo ".tables" | sqlite3 "$DB_FILE"

# See the schema of the database
echo Schema as follows:
echo ".schema" | sqlite3 "$DB_FILE"

# Insert a person
echo Inserting image
echo "INSERT INTO People (image,name) VALUES(readfile('smiley.png'),'smiley');" | sqlite3 "$DB_FILE"

# Display ids of all records present in the table "People"
echo The following records are in the databasae
sqlite3 "$DB_FILE" <<< "SELECT id,name FROM People;"

# Extract one record
echo Extracting image...
echo "SELECT writefile('extracted.png',image) FROM People WHERE name='smiley';" | sqlite3 "$DB_FILE"

Here are the two images:
 

Here is the Python to insert/extract an image:
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys
import sqlite3
from pathlib import Path
from PIL import Image
from io import BytesIO

DBFILENAME="example.db"

def insertBLOB(image, name):

    # Connect to database and insert image with given name
    with sqlite3.connect(DBFILENAME) as conn:
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        sql = """INSERT INTO People (image, name) VALUES (?, ?)"""
        data_tuple = (image, name)
        cursor.execute(sql, data_tuple)
        conn.commit()

def retrieveBLOB(name):

    # Connect to database and extract image with given name
    with sqlite3.connect(DBFILENAME) as conn:
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        sql = f"""SELECT image FROM People WHERE name = '{name}'"""
        cursor.execute(sql)
        blob = cursor.fetchone()[0]
    return blob

if __name__ == '__main__':

    # Check all required arguments present
    if len(sys.argv) != 4:
        print(f'Usage: {sys.argv[0]} insert|retrieve filename name', file=sys.stderr)
        sys.exit(1)

    # Pick up parameters
    filename = sys.argv[2]
    person   = sys.argv[3]

    if sys.argv[1] == 'insert':
        # Read image from disk, insert into db
        image = Path(filename).read_bytes()
        insertBLOB(image, person)
    else:
        # Retrieve image from db, write to disk
        image = retrieveBLOB(person)

        # If user only ever inserts JPEGs and only ever extracts JPEGs,
        # or, user only ever inserts/extracts PNGs,
        # we could just do the following single line and be finished
        # Path(filename).write_bytes(image)

        # However, if user can put in JPEG and get out a PNG, or vice-versa, we need PIL to convert
        pImage = Image.open(BytesIO(image)).convert('RGB')
        pImage.save(filename)

You can then add images like this:
./sqlite.py insert sad.png sad
./sqlite.py insert smiley.png smiley

and extract an image like this:
./sqlite.py retrieve extracted.png smiley

